# How to plot a ROC curve from Classification Tree probabilities

Tags: r, plot, classification, roc, auc

I am attempting to plot a ROC curve with classification trees probabilities.  However, when I plot the curve, it is absent.  I am trying to plot the ROC curve and then find the AUC value from the area under the curve. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thank you if you can. The binary column Risk stands for risk misclassification, which I presume is my label.  Should I be applying the ROC curve equation at a different point in my code?

Here is the data frame:

```
   library(ROCR)

   data(Risk.table)

   pred = prediction(Risk.table$Predicted.prob, Risk.table2$Risk)
   perf = performance(pred, measure="tpr", x.measure="fpr")
   perf
   plot(perf)

   Predicted.prob Actual.prob   predicted actual Risk
  1       0.5384615   0.4615385        G8     V4    0
  2       0.1212121   0.8787879        V4     V4    1
  3       0.5384615   0.4615385        G8     G8    1
  4       0.9000000   0.1000000        G8     G8    1
  5       0.1212121   0.8787879        V4     V4    1
  6       0.1212121   0.8787879        V4     V4    1
  7       0.9000000   0.1000000        G8     G8    1
  8       0.5384615   0.4615385        G8     V4    0
  9       0.5384615   0.4615385        G8     V4    0
  10      0.1212121   0.8787879        V4     G8    0
  11      0.1212121   0.8787879        V4     V4    1
  12      0.9000000   0.1000000        G8     V4    0
  13      0.9000000   0.1000000        G8     V4    0
  14      0.1212121   0.8787879        G8     V4    1
  15      0.9000000   0.1000000        G8     G8    1
  16      0.5384615   0.4615385        G8     V4    0
  17      0.9000000   0.1000000        G8     V4    0
  18      0.1212121   0.8787879        V4     V4    1
  19      0.5384615   0.4615385        G8     V4    0
  20      0.1212121   0.8787879        V4     V4    1
  21      0.9000000   0.1000000        G8     G8    1
  22      0.5384615   0.4615385        G8     V4    0
  23      0.9000000   0.1000000        G8     V4    0
  24      0.1212121   0.8787879        V4     V4    1
```

## Here is the ROC curve this code outputs, but the curve is missing:

[image]

## I tried again and this ROC curve is just wrong

[image]

## I constructed the above data frame using the code below:

## The initial data frame containing all the data is called shuffle.cross.validation2

```
  #Split data 70:30 after shuffling the data frame

  index<-1:nrow(LDA.scores1)
  trainindex.LDA3=sample(index, trunc(length(index)*0.70),replace=FALSE)      

  LDA.70.trainset3<-shuffle.cross.validation2[trainindex.LDA3,]

  LDA.30.testset3<-shuffle.cross.validation2[-trainindex.LDA3,]
```

## Run classification tree using package rpart()

```
 tree.split3<-rpart(Family~., data=LDA.70.trainset3, method="class")
 tree.split3
 summary(tree.split3)
 print(tree.split3)
 plot(tree.split3)
 text(tree.split3,use.n=T,digits=0)
 printcp(tree.split3)
 tree.split3
```

## Predict the predicted and actual data

```
 res3=predict(tree.split3,newdata=LDA.30.testset3)
 res4=as.data.frame(res3)
```

## Create two columns with NA's (Actual and predicted classification rate)

```
 res4$predicted<-NA
 res4$actual<-NA


 for (i in 1:length(res4$G8)){

 if(res4$R2[i]>res4$V4[i]) {
 res4$predicted[i]<-"G8"
 }

 else {
 res4$predicted[i]<-"V4"
 }

  print(i)
 }

 res4

 res4$actual<-LDA.30.testset3$Family
 res4
 Risk.table$Risk<-NA
 Risk.table
```

## Create the binary predictor column

```
  for (i in 1:length(Risk.table$Risk)){

  if(Risk.table$predicted[i]==res4$actual[i]) {
  Risk.table$Risk[i]<-1
  }

  else {
  Risk.table$Risk[i]<-0
  }

  print(i)
  }
```

## Creation of the predicted and actual probabilities for the two families V4 and G8 above

```
    #Confusion Matrix

    cm=table(res4$actual, res4$predicted)

    names(dimnames(cm))=c("actual", "predicted")
```

## Naive Bayes

```
  index<-1:nrow(significant.lda.Wilks2)
  trainindex.LDA.help1=sample(index, trunc(length(index)*0.70), replace=FALSE)                                     
  sig.train=significant.lda.Wilks2[trainindex.LDA.help1,]
  sig.test=significant.lda.Wilks2[-trainindex.LDA.help1,]


    library(klaR)
    nbmodel<-NaiveBayes(Family~., data=sig.train)
    prediction<-predict(nbmodel, sig.test)
    NB<-as.data.frame(prediction)
    colnames(NB)<-c("Actual", "Predicted.prob", "acual.prob")

    NB$actual2 = NA
    NB$actual2[NB$Actual=="G8"] = 1
    NB$actual2[NB$Actual=="V4"] = 0
    NB2<-as.data.frame(NB)

    plot(fit.perf, col="red"); #Naive Bayes
    plot(perf, col="blue", add=T); #Classification Tree
    abline(0,1,col="green")
```

[image]

## Original Naive Bayes code using the caret package

```
     library(caret)
     library(e1071)

  train_control<-trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=3)
  model<-train(Matriline~., data=LDA.scores, trControl=train_control,    method="nb")
  predictions <- predict(model, LDA.scores[,2:13])
  confusionMatrix(predictions,LDA.scores$Family)
```

## Results

```
               Confusion Matrix and Statistics

                        Reference
                Prediction V4 G8
                        V4 25  2
                        G8  5 48

                  Accuracy : 0.9125         
                    95% CI : (0.828, 0.9641)
       No Information Rate : 0.625          
       P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 4.918e-09      

                    Kappa : 0.8095         
   Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 0.4497         

              Sensitivity : 0.8333         
              Specificity : 0.9600         
           Pos Pred Value : 0.9259         
           Neg Pred Value : 0.9057         
               Prevalence : 0.3750         
           Detection Rate : 0.3125         
     Detection Prevalence : 0.3375         
        Balanced Accuracy : 0.8967         

         'Positive' Class : V4
```

Comment: In the `prediction` function your predictions and labels are from two different data frames, which probably isn't what you intended. Your plot *is* an ROC curve, but for a model that has exactly zero predictive power. When I run your code using `Predicted.prob` and `Risk` from the data you posted, I get an ROC curve, but it's below the 45 degree line because the predictions and labels are anti-correlated.

Comment: Also, your code includes `data(Risk.table)`, but as far as I can tell, there's no package that includes a data frame called `Risk.table`.

Comment: Should I be applying the ROC curve equation higher at a different point in the code?  Thank you for your comment

Comment: Hi epic, sorry, Risk.table is just the name of the above data.frame. I achieved the probabilities in this data frame by running the extra code I have supplied. I did a predication on the classification because I was making a confusion matrix, hence the Predicted Prob and the Acutual Prob columns.  These probabilities were derived  from  the catergorical-dependent column in my initial data frame containing all the values (shuffle.cross.validated2) containing two classes V4 and G8.

Comment: It will be much easier to help you if you include a data sample in your question with which we can run (and fix or improve) your code. For now, one thing you can do is get rid of the for loops and take advantage of R's vectorization instead. For example: `Risk.table$Risk = ifelse(Risk.table$predicted==res4$actual, 1,0)`.

Comment: The second ROC curve that you added to your question is the correct ROC curve for the `Risk.table` data you posted. Note that the correlation of `Risk.table$Predicted.prob` and `Risk.table$Actual.prob` is -1. When your predictions are the anti-correlated with the true values (which indicates something wrong with your model and/or your code), the ROC curve will be below the diagonal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have various things to point out:

1)  I think your code has to be `Family ~ .` inside your rpart command.

2)  In your initial table I can see a value `W3` in your predicted column. Does that mean you don’t have a binary dependent variable? ROC curves work with binary data, so check it.

3) Your predicted and actual probabilities in your initial table always sum to 1. Is that reasonable? I think they represent something else, so you might consider changing names in case they confuse you in the future.

4)  I think you’re confused about how ROC works and what inputs it needs. Your `Risk` column uses 1 to represent a correct prediction and 0 to represent a wrong prediction. However, the ROC curve needs 1 to represent one class and 0 to represent the other class. In simple words, the command is `prediction(predictions, labels)` where `predictions` are your predicted probabilities and `labels` are the true class/levels of your dependent variable.
Check the following code:

```
dt = read.table(text="
Id Predicted.prob Actual.prob   predicted actual Risk
1       0.5384615   0.4615385        G8     V4    0
2       0.1212121   0.8787879        V4     V4    1
3       0.5384615   0.4615385        G8     G8    1
4       0.9000000   0.1000000        G8     G8    1
5       0.1212121   0.8787879        V4     V4    1
6       0.1212121   0.8787879        V4     V4    1
7       0.9000000   0.1000000        G8     G8    1
8       0.5384615   0.4615385        G8     V4    0
9       0.5384615   0.4615385        G8     V4    0
10      0.1212121   0.8787879        V4     G8    0
11      0.1212121   0.8787879        V4     V4    1
12      0.9000000   0.1000000        G8     V4    0
13      0.9000000   0.1000000        G8     V4    0
14      0.1212121   0.8787879        W3     V4    1
15      0.9000000   0.1000000        G8     G8    1
16      0.5384615   0.4615385        G8     V4    0
17      0.9000000   0.1000000        G8     V4    0
18      0.1212121   0.8787879        V4     V4    1
19      0.5384615   0.4615385        G8     V4    0
20      0.1212121   0.8787879        V4     V4    1
21      0.9000000   0.1000000        G8     G8    1
22      0.5384615   0.4615385        G8     V4    0
23      0.9000000   0.1000000        G8     V4    0
24      0.1212121   0.8787879        V4     V4    1", header=T)

library(ROCR)

roc_pred <- prediction(dt$Predicted.prob, dt$Risk)
perf <- performance(roc_pred, "tpr", "fpr")
plot(perf, col="red")
abline(0,1,col="grey")
```

The ROC curve is :

[image]

When you create a new column `actual2` where you have 1 instead of G8 and 0 instead of V4:

```
dt$actual2 = NA
dt$actual2[dt$actual=="G8"] = 1
dt$actual2[dt$actual=="V4"] = 0

roc_pred <- prediction(dt$Predicted.prob, dt$actual2)
perf <- performance(roc_pred, "tpr", "fpr")
plot(perf, col="red")
abline(0,1,col="grey")
```

[image]

5) As @eipi10 mentioned above, you should try to get rid of the for loops in your code.

Comment: Thank you Antoniosk.  This is brilliant.  I have been playing around with this for ages and just have not got anywhere.  You are a legend.  Thank you again :)

Comment: Glad I helped. Another useful command is `performance(roc_pred,"auc")@y.values` , which will give you the area under the curve in case you need to compare models.

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to do.  I used two supervised machine learning techniques and I want to compare the differences between Naive Bayes (NB)  and this classification tree.  Would you have any ideas with how to plot both the results for the NB and the classification tree on the same ROC curve, then calculate the AUC to compare them:

Comment: Using the same script you need to create `roc_pred1` and `perf1` for one model and `roc_pred2` and `perf2` for the other one and then do 
`plot(perf1, col="red");
plot(perf2, col="blue", add=T);
abline(0,1,col="grey")` . For the auc curve just use `performance(roc_pred1,"auc")@y.values` and `performance(roc_pred2,"auc")@y.values`

Comment: AntoniosK.  Look what I did above.  Thanks a million.  You are a life saver :) So happy you commented on this problem and perhaps this will help others.  Take care

Comment: Looks good and correct as a process, but I have to point out that the blue line (classification tree) looks suspiciously good. Actually that's the perfect ROC curve! Did you expect that based on your data? Any chance there's something wrong?

Comment: That's what I thought.  I initially did the NB test using the caret package, and the classification accuracy score was 91 % (code has been inserted above). I was unsure how to convert the code and results from the confusion matrix into a ROC curve. Therefore, I moved over to the  klar package. The code for the classification trees in the rpart package and the NB test has been run on data with exactly the same format. Have you got any suggestions? –

Comment: I don't think there's a way to turn confusion matrices to ROC curves, because what you need to build the ROC curve is a vector of predicted probabilities (values from 0 to 1 and not predicted classes 0/1) and the actual classes (0/1), as I mentioned above. You have to be able to use both models to predict probabilities like `pred_prob_model1` and `pred_prob_model2` (vectors of predicted probability values from 0 to 1, using model 1 and 2) and plot them against the actual classes (0/1) you have using the ROC process.

Comment: I used the same methodology for the NB and the classification tree and there is definitely something wrong with a classification accuracy rate of 1.0.  I will have to go back to the drawing board.  Would I use the same methodology to plot a linear discriminant score onto the ROC curve too?