# How to estimate correctness and fit of a model (estimator)

Tags: r, predict

I have a decision tree (but the question is general for any other estimating model).

```
models[[1]]<- J48(NSP~., data=training)
```

I would like to see how good is the model over the testing data:

```
pred <- predict(models[[1]], testing)
```

I would like to get the number of correct estimations of the models[[1]] versus the actual one (in NSP column of the testing). How can I do it?

Is there any other way to estimate how good does my model (models[[1]]) or how much it fits the data?

Comment: Is this actually a statistical question, for cross-validated? or just about the programming?

Comment: This is a about the programming aspect. The practical implementation.

Comment: It would be good to see if your tree is a classification or regression tree. In other words if your NSP is categorical (maybe binary) or continuous/scale. If it's binary then you need to find out how to use a confusion matrix (simply a cross-tabulation) and how to plot and interpret an ROC curve. These will be helpful : http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/171915/r-classification-ctree-party-testing-sample-and-leaf-attribution-with-unba/172088#172088 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32292905/how-to-plot-a-roc-curve-from-classification-tree-probabilities/32328592#32328592

Comment: Thanks a lot AntoniosK! NSP is categorical it can have 3 possible values: 1, 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
mean (pred == testing$NSP)
```

Comment: Could you edit your answer to add a little explanation of how this solves the question?